# Don't want to repeat a rand after reloding page (PHP)

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have created a form that should submit some content in the database. A make an random numberstring and then when a submit I want the content insert into database. But before submit the random numbers is repeated and I got a new one. How to eliminate that?

```
<?php

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

$random = rand(1000, 2000)

$dedu = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_password ='$random'");

$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_password = ?");

$query->bindValue(1, $password);

$dedu->execute();
$query->execute();
$num = $query->rowCount();

if ($num == 1) {

if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {

$error = 'All fields are requried';
} else {

 $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content) Values    (?, ?)');

$query->bindValue(1, $title);
$query->bindValue(2, $content);


$query->execute();

$msg = 'You added the following article!';


}

}





} else {

$error = 'Incorrect details!';
}




?>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>dwa</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
   <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
    <br />


<h4>Add Article</h4>

<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
<div class="error">
  <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>

  <form action="test.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" /><br />
  <textarea rows="15" cols="50"  placeholder="content" name="content"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Article" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />

  </form>






  <?php if (isset($msg)) { ?>
  <div class="msg">
  <small style="color:orange"><?php echo $msg;?> <br /><H3>
  <?php echo $title; ?></h3><h5><?php echo $content; ?></h5></small>
  </div><?php } ?>  


  </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: $random = rand(1000, 2000) put a semicolon to the end, like $random = rand(1000, 2000):

Comment: use cookie concept....

Comment: It's PHP, ditch cookies and use sessions if it's a one-way ticket.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement looks like it is free of SQL injection, but nevertheless it is a good idea to use binding here too. Also, passwords should not be stored in plain text.

Comment: So how to take care of the SQL injections? @halfer

Comment: You're doing it correctly for your `SELECT` statement, by using `bindValue()`. Do the same for your `UPDATE`.

Comment: So something like this? $query->bindValue(1, $random); @halfer

Comment: Yes, that's right. Why not give it a go?

Comment: What do you mean with that? (Give it a go) @halfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a session!

If the session is false the rand function runs and the session is set to true. When the page reloads(submit pressed) the session is true so all the other cod runs. In the end of the code (if session is true) the session is destroyd. Because If the user want a new rand the reload the page and the rand function runs again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly what you want to achieve but try putting

$random = rand(1000, 2000)

after

$query->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Use this cookie concept in your file

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = "John Doe";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        //dont do anything
    } else {
        $random = rand(1000, 2000);
    }........proceed with your code
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['password']))$password = $_POST['password']; 
else $random = rand(1000, 2000);
```